# Почему z-index не реагирует?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, позиционирование

Я спозиционировал тёмное меню, которое задано с помощью `position: absolute; z-index: 1`, оно находится выше всех, но я хочу, чтобы кнопка, которая была в header стала выше, я пытался добавлять `z-index: 2`, но ничего не работает.

 
https://mihinov.github.io/news/ Тут смотреть
Чтобы открылось меню, надо кликнуть на бургер меню
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После нажатия на меню появляется затемнённый блок, и на кнопку нельзя кликнуть, так как она "ниже" тёмного фона

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Наследник не может быть выше родителя по индексу.

Comment: Но тёмный фон это не родитель же. У меня сначала идёт `<header>`, а после него `<div class="burger__menu">`

Comment: у header'a какой индекс ?

Comment: @NeedHate, у `header` [1] индекс, понял

Comment: если у header'a убрать белый фон и нижнюю границу и добавить z-index: 3 , то должно быть симпатично, ну или переходами делать фон прозрачным и границу тоже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо убрать `z-index` у хэдера и поставить крестику `z-index` больше чем у оверлея. Если содержимому хэдера нужен `z-index`, то надо всё кроме крестика обернуть в блок, которому поставить соответствующий `z-index` меньше оверлея.